# default port of clickhouse did not change after I modify config.xml

Tags: clickhouse

I'm new to `clickhouse`.

Because my `hadoop` use the port 9000,conflict with `clickhouse`'s default port

Here's my steps to modify the port:

①sudo gedit /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml change all 9000 to 9500

②sudo service clickhouse-server restart

③clickhouse-client -u default  --password

Connecting to localhost:9000 as user default.
Code: 210. DB::NetException: Connection refused (localhost:9000)

④clickhouse-client -u default --port 9500 --password

then connection is OK

## -------------------------------------

My question is:

In the future,there will be other needs to modify the config.xml

why my modification did not take effect after I restart clickhouse sevice?

Thanks for for your reading and help~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clickhouse-client -- different application and it's a client and it has own configuration /etc/clickhouse-client/

By default it tries to connect to localhost:9000 . It has no information that clickhouse-server uses the port 9500

You can override default port for the client

```
cat /etc/clickhouse-client/config.xml

<config>
    <port>9500</port>
....
```

Comment: for me, it worked after changing the file: `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml`
`<tcp_port>8080</tcp_port>`
And /etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/listen.xml to:
        `<listen_port>8080</listen_port>`